# Remove RelationshipManager JSON from WebAPI output

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently building a RESTful API with WebAPI and Entity Framework. All is going well - having solved the nasty circular reference problem to, except my output contains a RelationshipManager JSON block, which bloats the output and I don't have much need for it in most cases.

Is there a way to remove it? Ignore it?

Here is the JSON I refer:-

```
{
$id: "1",
RelationshipManager: {},
AirlineId: 1,
AirlineName: "British Airways",
Code: "BA",
Url: "www.ba.com",
Seo: null
},
{
$id: "3",
RelationshipManager: {
$id: "4",
_owner: {
$ref: "3"
},
_relationships: null
},
AirlineId: 2,
AirlineName: "Delta",
Code: "DL",
Url: "www.delta.com",
Seo: null
},
```

Help is appreciated ;)

Comment: The obvious answer: use DTO's. More work, less frustration.

Comment: Defeats the reason I used EF though. The architecture of the data is fluid at the moment, I don't want the maintenance nightmare everytime I make a change on the database.  Quite frankly, if this is the only issue I have with EF and WebAPI, I'll take it because of the huge saving it gives.

Comment: I have the same issue... can you pls advise how to fix this?

Comment: @Krunel, the only way to remove the block is to create a custom DTO and populate it.  I did this in the end as otherwise I was coupling my EF objects to the front-end which would be bad practise anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to remove the block seems to be to create your own custom DTO objects and marshall data from EF into them in your BLL.  It did occur to me that it would be bad practise to surface EF objects in the front-end/api anyway.